# How to solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1-x^2+y^2}{2xy}$

Tags: integration

I'm having trouble in trying to make  $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1-x^2+y^2}{2xy}$ a variable separable equation so I can integrate it. Any ideas?

Comment: Solve as Bernoulli's/homogeneous equation

Comment: @Nehorai, it is really a homogeneous equation?

Comment: Use the implicit function theorem. If you know multivariable calculus.

Comment: $y=\pm\sqrt{1-\dfrac{x^2}3+\dfrac Cx}$

Comment: @Agarwal, is that the thrm where you add a new variable z?

Comment: @Lucian, could you please explain in detail how you derived it?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$
\,d\left(\frac{y^2}{x}\right) = \frac{2xy dy - y^2 dx}{x^2} = \left(\frac{1}{x^2} - 1\right)\,dx
$$

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm afraid I do not understand the concept of d(y^2/x). Could you please explain?

Comment: This is a exact differential.

Comment: This is an alternative use of integrating factor.  You can also directly compute the integrating factor, like [this](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/intfactor/intfactor.html), and then make it an exact function.

Answer (score 1):

$$2xyy'=1-x^2+y^2$$
$u=y^2$ and $u'=2yy'$
$$xu'-u=1-x^2$$
is a linear ODE easy to solve :

First, solve the associated homogeneous ODE : $xU'-U=0$ which gives $U=Cx$

Second, replace the constant $C$ by a function $f(x)$, hense $u=(f(x))x$ and $u'=f+xf'$
$$xu'-u=x(f+xf')-xf=x^2f'=1-x^2$$
$$f'=\frac{1}{x^2}-1$$
$$f=-\frac{1}{x}-x+c$$
$$u=xf=-1-x^2+cx$$
$$y=\pm\sqrt{u}=\pm \sqrt{-1-x^2+cx}$$

Comment: I give up. I don't know these kinds of techniques. Could you please expound further? I would be very greatful.

Comment: It is essential to learn the classical method of solving the first order linear ODEs such as $xu'-u=1-x^2$ for example.